# django doesn't render a first <form> tag in the template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a base template to extend:

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}


<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">        
        
        {% block title %}
            <title>taskmanager</title>
        {% endblock title %}
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'common_static/base/styles/base.css' %}">
        
        {% block extrahead %}{% endblock extrahead %}
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header-main-area center-area">
                
                <div id="switch-lang" class="header-element">
                    {% include 'svgpaths/language_icon.html' %}
                    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                    {% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as current_language %}
                    <div class="header-element-caption"> {{ current_language.name_local }}</div>
                    
                        <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" class="lang-dropdown dropdown-content">{% csrf_token %}
                        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                        
                        {% for language in languages %}
                            <button type="submit" name="language" value={{ language.code }} class="dropdown-item">{{ language.name_local }}</button>
                        {% endfor %}
                </div>
                
                <div id="account" class="header-element">
                    {% include 'svgpaths/account_icon.html' %}

                    {% if username %}
                    <div class="header-element-caption">{{ username }}</div>
                    {% else %}
                    <div class="header-element-caption">{% translate "account" %}</div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="acconunt-dropdown dropdown-content">
                        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="dropdown-item">{% translate "log out" %}</a>
                        <a href={% url 'user_settings' %}><div class="dropdown-item">{% translate "settings" %}</div></a>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
            <main>
                
                {% block maincontent %}
                    <h1>This is the base templated for extending</h1>
                {% endblock maincontent %}

            </main>
                {% block bodybottom %}{% endblock bodybottom %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and a template which a want to use to extend base template:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}


{% block title %}
    <title>{% translate "logginig in" %}</title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'users/style/authpages.css' %}">
{% endblock extrahead %}

{% block maincontent %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" class="main-form">
        
        {% csrf_token %}

        <label for="username">{% translate "User name: " %}</label>
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.username.errors }}

        <label for="password">{% translate "Password: " %} </label>
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.password.errors }}

        {% if form.errors %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {% endif %}

        <input type="submit" value="{% translate 'sign in' %}">
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">

        <a href="{% url 'register' %}">{% translate "Register" %}</a>
    </form>
{% endblock maincontent %}
```

the {% block maincontent %} (almost on the bottom of the page) contents a piece of html starting with the `<form>` html tag and some "django-form related stuff" within it. The problem is, that when I load the page, Django renders all of the form's fields within the `<form>` tag but ignores the `<form>` tag itself:

```
<main>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="LbJ3lrEw3qD3JtoDH7COpwzVWdQXwRzIuy9CaViWH0Liom8EAiI4TsjVP4wAooJa">
        <label for="username">User name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" maxlength="150" required="" id="id_username">
        <label for="password">Password:  </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" required="" id="id_password">
        <input type="submit" value="sign in">
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="">
        <a href="/accounts/register">Register</a>
</main>
```

The only way I have figured out to avoid this issue is to put another blank `<form></form>` tag right before my actual form. In this case, Django ignores the "dummy" form and renders my actual form well. Is it a bug or I missing something about template processing in the Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your base template, you have a form tag without a closing tag. That's the problem add the closing tag and it will render your form.

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" class="lang-dropdown dropdown-content">

// add the closing tag
</form>
```

Comment: oh.. it's such embarrassing. Thank you for your answer!